# Best Approach to Keep Continuous Location of a Vehicle

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am in the midst of programming an HTML5 (with C# backend) site that needs to keep a continuous log of the location of a vehicle and map its location in google maps

My thoughts were require the driver of the vehicle to have a browser open to a specific page and to use JavaScript and a timeout to basically send the GPS coordinates of the vehicle to the database on a specified interval and then pull the coordinates to create the "path traveled/traveling" in a google map.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this approach, pros? cons? Before I get too far into the coding?

The part I am having second thoughts about is if the vehicle is out of cellular range; my assumption is that those requests to update the DB with the coordinates of the vehicle will fail (obviously) but when they reach cellular service again, they will succeed and I can map the travel(ed/ing) path from the last known, to the most recent.

Any nuances anyone has experienced taking this approach?

Needs to work on IE 10+, Google Chrome, Safari (iPhone/iPad version), FireFox (+/- 3 releases from latest release since they release so often)

Comment: Open a socket and keep sending. Since the connection will be open. Will also reconnect by itself if network breaks

Comment: Would I have to use any third party libraries, or just out of the box JavaScript?

Comment: `socket.io` library  is a good bet.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed the similar application but in android, implemented the same logic of auto-update of location on regular interval. So, this is totally good way of implementing real time location application.

For the issue of out of cellular range, if you don't want to lost location data that being tracked during off-range situation, and when keeping record of complete location data is important, you can simply implement a buffer on which you regularly save the location data (e.g. storing on local array) when internet connection is not available and push the buffer to database when connection available. This way, you can pull complete traveled path instead of partial that was lost by out of cellular range.